# Getting the workflow associated to a node type

Tags: workflows

How do i get the workflow entity associated to a certain node bundle? So far my approach has been to use EntityTypeManager to load the workflow config entity storage and trying to load the right workflow using loadByProperties() function,

```php
$workflow = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('workflow')->loadByProperties();
```

except I don't know what properties I should be specifying or If I'm approaching this the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workflows are configuration entities so you can load them using their id:

```
$workflow = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('workflow')->load('workflow_machine_name');
```

Or "query" them using the Entity Query (check the Drupal 8 example shown [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1827278)):

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('workflow')->getQuery();
$query->condition('type_settings.entity_types.node', 'article', 'IN');
$workflows = $query->execute();
```

The condition is a proof-of-concept drawn from another config entity query but is the right path you need to test it agains the workflow entity schema.

Comment: Thank you! this worked for me, specifically getting the query object and specifying the condition. Executing the query gives you an array with workflow entity id. You can then use the id in the array to load the config entity using the example above `$workflow = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('workflow')->load('workflow_machine_name');` .

Comment: Although this answer is very helpful, the query code isn't quite right and doesn't work. The condition should be `$query->condition('type_settings.entity_types.node.*', 'article');` which filters the array `type_settings.entity_types.node` by the value 'article'.